# VSCode color theme function calls

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate, color-scheme

I am doing my own local tweaks to [this color theme](https://github.com/kcmr/electron-theme-vscode/blob/master/themes/electron-color-theme.json) for VSCode. The theme will be used to mainly code in Java and C++.

I would like function and method declaration color to be different from function and method invocation calls.

So the word Foo in the following two instances would be a different color...

```
public void Foo(String s, int d) {
}

someClass.Foo("blah" , 2);
```

Currently the block of code that is setting the color for functions in this is as follows

```
{
  "name": "Functions",
  "scope": "entity.name.function, meta.require, support.function.any-method",
  "settings": {
    "foreground": "#e26660"
  }
},
```

I would be ok if function invocation used the default foreground text color.

Comment: Did you try examining the two scopes with the "Developer: Inspect TM Scopes" command and see it they differ?  If they do, you should be able to separately target those scopes.  I am not running java or C++ files to check.

Comment: I don't have such a command available to me in the command palette.

Comment: In vscode you don't have that?  That is weird.

Comment: Correct, I do not have it. I am running version 1.27.2 (user setup).

Comment: @ScottF Make sure you are focused on a text editor with syntax highlighting when you search the command palette for that command

Comment: If they are the same scope, I don't think you can do it with the usual editor.tokenColorCustomizations scoping.  Are you open to a regex solution to find and style declarations differently from invocations?

Answer (score 2):

For function call set color for the following scopes add the folowing settings:

```
{
  "name": "Function call",
  "scope": "meta.function-call.generic, meta.function-call.object, meta.function-call.static",
  "settings": {
    "foreground": "#e26f60"
  }
},
```

also, you might be able to set the color for only CPP by setting the scope of

```
meta.function-call.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer for you for C++!

For function calls:

```
{
    "name": "Function calls",
    "scope": [
        "entity.name.function.call.cpp",
            
    ],
    "settings": {
    "foreground": "#9bff6d"
    }
},
```

and for declarations:

```
    {
        "name": "Function declarations",
        "scope": [
            "entity.name.function.definition.cpp",
            
        ],
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ffc66d"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a scope-based answer, you can do this with more work via a regex based approach.  Using an extension like [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) which allows you to specify synatx highlighting for strings that can be captured via regular expressions.  For example,

```
 "highlight.regexes": {

    "(\\b.*\\.)([^(\\s]*)(\\s*\\(.*\\))": {

      "regexFlags": "g",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "(java|cpp)",
      \\ "filterFileRegex" : ".*\\.java",
      "decorations" : [
        {},  // first capture group, " do nothing
        {  "color": "red",
         "fontWeight": "bold",
         "padding": "3px",  // only pads top and bottom unfortunately
         "backgroundColor": "darkgreen",
        //  "border": "1px solid white",
        //  "borderRadius": "4px"
        },
        {}  // third capture group, ", do nothing
      ]
    },

    "((?:void|int)\\s+)([^(\\s]*)(\\s*\\(.*\\))": {

      "regexFlags": "g",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "(java|cpp)",
      \\ "filterFileRegex" : ".*\\.java",
      "decorations" : [
        {},  // first capture group, " do nothing
        {  "color": "red",
         "fontWeight": "bold",
         "padding": "3px",  // only pads top and bottom unfortunately
         "backgroundColor": "darkgreen",
        //  "border": "1px solid white",
        //  "borderRadius": "4px"
        },
        {}  // third capture group, ", do nothing
      ]
    }
```

The first of those captures calls like `someClass.Foo("blah" , 2);` with `Foo` in the second capture group.

The second of those captures calls like `public void Foo(String s, int d)` with `Foo` in the second capture group.

I have simplified the second regex a bit (I added only `void` and `int`, but you could easily add the other alternatives).

[image: java code highlighted]